# Produce different html view in each cycle

Tags: html, asp.net, view, webforms, multiview

please help about this.

How can i produce different html view in each cycle. I can do with MVC but can not do with ASP.NET Web Form. Can it do with Repeater( or ListView ) and MultiView?

Thanks for everything.

```
<div id="movieResults">
    @foreach (var movie in HomeController.Movies)
    {
        if(Condition)
        {
            Block of HTML1
        }
        else if(Condition)
        {
            Another Block of HTML2
        }
        else if(Condition)
        {
            Another Block of HTML3
        }

    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UserControl`

**UControl.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="UControl" %>
<div>Control Content</div>
```

**UcontrolView.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="MyCustomControl" Src="~/Controls/UControl.ascx" %>
<html>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <uc:MyCustomControl id="MyPartialView" runat="server" />
</form>
</body>
```

You can refer 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53(v=vs.100).aspx